# Please help; this is giving me an ulcer -walled, -wall, or no wall at all?

Tags: past-participles, adjective-phrases, hyphens, participial-adjectives

Okay, so I'm editing a book on architecture that's as poorly written as it is dry. My biggest issue right now is the use of the word "walled"; do you think this needs to be rewritten as present tense "wall" not "walled"? Or does wall need to be deleted in its entirety? (e.g., "concrete block trashcan enclosure"). Ugh, this is giving me an ulcer. Please help!

The house is approached on a porous, oyster shell driveway that begins at the corner of Clifton and Sandra Roads, passes the hexagonal **concrete block–walled** trashcan enclosure (designed by Ernest as a hint of what is to come, but which was not built), and bends to the south, where the oyster shell parking area for guests fronts onto the two openings of the large hexagonal carport.

The carport is the largest and most geometrically regular space in the house, comprising six of the 16-foot-sided triangles arranged to form a hexagonal space, with **solid-walled** storage closets to the north and south, and is given the same lowest ceiling (fig.3b.14).

The 36x44-foot ground floorplan has a long, shallow entry porch, with doors to the maid’s room and den at its two ends, and the **glass-walled** entry into the foyer and stair hall at the center.

Comment: It's fine. Your question does not make clear why you think it might not be.

Comment: Its fine, but I would also be happy with *"hexagonal concrete block trashcan enclosure"*.

Answer (score 1):

The word "walled" is a participle formed from a now mostly obsolete verb "to wall" (meaning to surround by a wall - some phrasal verbs like "to wall in" remain current).  You can use "walled" to mean "surrounded by a wall.

> He entered the walled garden. / York is a walled city.

Compounds can be freely formed "high-walled" = surrounded by high walls.  "concrete-walled" = surrounded by walls made of concrete.

So the trashcan enclosure is surrounded by walls made of concrete blocks.